# Bug when running app "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a completed code for a small app I am made and are now stuck on

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Anyone have the time to help me by looking over the code and see what to do when it comes to fixing it. I am a rookie when it comes to programming.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var panelWidthTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var panelHightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var panelsWideTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var panelsHightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var panelPitchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultWithLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultHightLabel: UILabel!


    // Removes keyboard when touch outside edit field.
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    // Disable button when there is no value in all fields
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {


        if ((panelWidthTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) &&
            (panelsWideTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) &&
            (panelHightTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) &&
            (panelPitchTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil))
        {
            self.calculateButton.enabled = true
        } else {
            self.calculateButton.enabled = false

        }           
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        panelWidthTextField.delegate = self
        panelsWideTextField.delegate = self
        panelHightTextField.delegate = self
        panelsHightTextField.delegate = self
        panelPitchTextField.delegate = self


    }
    // Sends calculation to resolution Display
        func calculatePressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let w = Double(panelWidthTextField.text!)
        let sw = Double(panelsWideTextField.text!)
        let pi = Double(panelPitchTextField.text!)
        let sizew = SizeWidthModel(pw:w!,psw:sw!,ptc:pi!)
        resultWithLabel.text=String(sizew.width())

        let h = Double(panelHightTextField.text!)
        let sh = Double(panelsHightTextField.text!)
        let sizeh = SizeHightModel(ph:h!,psh:sh!,ptc:pi!)
        resultHightLabel.text=String(sizeh.hight())
    }            
}
```

[Error that comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN2Ys.png)

I am trying do disable the one button I have until all fields are filled in.

Latest error after some fixing

[Latest error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpZ4.png)

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but there are hundreds of questions about the very same error message (for example all questions in the "Related" section). What do you know about optionals and what have you done to isolate the problem? Did you set a breakpoint to verify that `self.calculateButton` is not `nil`? Did you double-check that the button is correctly connected in the interface builder?

Comment: @Martin R I know there are hundreds of the same question, but since I am such a n00b at this I just cand seem to find out what goes wrong. I have spent days looking for a way to sort this out, but with no luck. It´s a simple task if you have the experience witch I do not have yet. The whole app runs fine until I select the second TextField out of any.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your IBOutlest are connected with Storyboard. You can identify these connections through little circle with selected dot (Refer the attached image). Or you can print each UITextField and check the nil exception is occurred ?.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(panelWidthTextField.text)
    print(panelsHightTextField.text) // I missed to connect outlet so it will throw nil
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, all my IBOutlets are connected with storyboard. The main problem when pressing Calculate button without anything in the fields the app crashes as you se om my attached picture.